# Trimming data frame in R with grep?

Tags: r, dataframe

My dataframe, dat, has two columns which look like this:

```
value   condition
2       learning/cat
4       learning/dog
1       naming/cat
6       naming/dog
```

I would like to 'trim' the data frame to only include rows in which condition contains "naming".

I've tried to do this with grep:

```
dat = dat[grep("naming", dat$condition, value = T)]
```

which causes the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(dat, grep("naming", dat$condition, value = T)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Can anyone suggest a fix? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `dat [grep("naming", dat$condition),]`

Comment: you missed a comma in the brackets: `dat = dat[grep("naming", dat$condition, value = T), ]`

Comment: @RyanMorton if i keep the `value=T` , it will return All `NA`

Comment: That's a different issue.  The error noted in the question has to do with the bracket subset not defining the columns.

Comment: Another choice is `dat[grepl("naming", dat$condition), ]`.
`

Comment: @RyanMorton `value = T` returns the actual string matched. It is not helpful for subsetting the data frame.

Comment: That's fine, but it's also not helpful to suggest that removing the value = T will solve the error when it doesn't.

Comment: It's in the original question, I just inserted the comma without amending anything else.  it's all good.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! Adding in the missing comma resolved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can split up condition using `separate` from `tidyr`:

```
df = input_df %>% separate( condition, into = c("condition1", "condition2"), sep = "/")
```

Then just use filter:

```
only_naming_df = df %>% filter(condition1 == "naming")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is easy to fix once adding a comma after the parenthesis. But I want to have a list of available options to achieve this task. Belows are solution and comments from others and mine.

#### Use grep or grepl

`grep` returns the index (row number), while `grepl` returns a logical vector (TRUE or FALSE). Notice that when using `grep` in this case, `value = T` should not be added because it will return the string, which is not helpful for subsetting.

```
dat[grep("naming", dat$condition), ]
dat[grepl("naming", dat$condition), ]
```

#### Functions from dplyr and stringr

`str_detect` is equivalent to `grepl(pattern, x)`, while `str_which` is equivalent to `grep(pattern, x)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat %>% filter(str_detect(condition, "naming"))
dat %>% slice(str_which(condition, "naming"))
```

#### Data Preparation

```
# Create example dataframes
dat <- read.table(text = "value   condition
2       learning/cat
4       learning/dog
1       naming/cat
6       naming/dog",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! Adding in the missing comma resolved the original issue, and I removed value = True.  Thanks!